# Pass parameters to all views

Tags: variables, groovy, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a play application (Play 1.2.4). In each page in my application I want to have access to the logged in user (using groovy).  So I can perform permission check etc.  I tried to put this in the main template just before the `doLayout`

```
#{set user:user/}
```

I can have access to the user in the main page of my application, but when going through links to other pages I can no longer have access to the user variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had misunderstanding about using `#{set}` and `#{get}` tag on Play!Framework. Look at the documentation on [`#{set}`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/tags#set) and [`#{get}`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/tags#get) tag.

I give you example, you have three templates like follows:

#### main.html

```html
<html>
   <head>
       <title>#{get 'title' /}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       #{doLayout /}
   </body>
</html>
```

#### template1.html

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:header /}

<p>This is template1.html page</p>
```

#### template2.html

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:header /}

<p>This is template2.html page</p>
```

And the methods on controllers like these:

```
public static void template1() {
    String header = "Template 1 Title"
    render(header);
}

public static void template2() {
    render();
}
```

This is the explanation, when you render `template1.html`, you may notice that we are set the page title (by using `header` variable) in `template1.html`. The title that we set, is retrieved on `main.html` by using `#{get}` on `main.html`.

Then look when you render `template2.html`, you may notice we are set the page title too. But the difference is in the **controllers** (on `template2()` method), you have not passed `header` variable value to the template. So, although you have set the title, the title have null value and the implication the title was not set when you render `template2.html`.

So, for your problem, I think when you insist to place `#{set user:user /}` on template and want to access `user` variable, you must pass the `user` variable on **all controller methods** before rendering the template. Ugh.. It's so inefficient!

---

> ### Suggestion
>
> I suggest you that you may use `session` to store the user data like `userid`, because it is accessible in all your application templates! Please look at the documentation [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/templates#implicits).

Hope this can make you understand the mechanism and will so

Comment: what will be the best place in code to do a renderArgs.put("user-id", userID);

Comment: The `renderArgs.put(key, value)` should be placed in the Controller. But why you choose use `renderArgs.put` to store the `userID` info? Calling `renderArgs.put(key, value)` is the similar thing like passing the variable to each template. I would like to suggest you to store it on `session` object to store userID information, so it can be accessed until the session expired.. :)

Comment: that's a good idea.BUT.. the user id is already in the session,and i wanted to pass MORE parameters template pages so i used         (@Before(only={"index", "pagex", "pagey")) ,and userId as a parameter is more easy to access in groovy, also want my cookies small to make less data in each request. dose  placing renderArgs param in a @before method is the best practice ? is it slow ?

Comment: I think `@Before` can be good choice too, if you don't want to store the data in session. You can use `@Before(unless={"pageA","pageB"})` annotation if you want to intercept all action except `pageA` and `pageB`, too. And you must know that using `@Before` is works apply to current **controller** and its descendant. But, with `userid` data stored on session, you can easily invalidate user session if expired. So, it is your preference, friend. ;)